# Kubernetes authentication and authorization with LDAP server

Tags: kubernetes, ldap

I would like to integrate Kubernetes with an LDAP server. On a Kubernetes cluster, I am going to have two different applications, each on its own namespace. If user A belongs to team A, should see the resources just from namespace A and if user B belongs to team B, he should see the resources just from namespace B. Kubernetes should do the authorization with the user to the specific resources based on LDAP server profile.

Is any way to integrate such an architecture with Kubernetes and LDAP server?

Comment: https://itnext.io/implementing-ldap-authentication-for-kubernetes-732178ec2155

Comment: @HarshManvar: Thank you for your reply. I was finding this link as well, but it looks like when compiling the Go package, I am getting permission denied when trying to listen on 443 even though the LDAP server works with https. Have you tried this method before?